# how to find which day it is of the week in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I want to know which day it is of the week, can anyone help me?

```
DAY: 

MOV AH,2AH    ; To get System Date
INT 21H
MOV AL,DL     ; Day is in DL
AAM
MOV BX,AX
CALL DISP

    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h  

DISP PROC
MOV DL,BH      ; Since the values are in BX, BH Part
ADD DL,30H     ; ASCII Adjustment
MOV AH,02H     ; To Print in DOS
INT 21H
MOV DL,BL      ; BL Part 
ADD DL,30H     ; ASCII Adjustment
MOV AH,02H     ; To Print in DOS
INT 21H
RET
DISP ENDP
```

Its only showing date but I want current day too.

Comment: Please fix the formatting, your question is unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very first Google search hit for 'int21H functions' gave me:

> ```
>    Function 2Ah - Get system date
>
>    Action:    Returns the system day, month and year plus the day of the week. 
>
> On entry: 
> AH = 2Ah
>
> Returns:
> CX = year (1980 to 2099) 
> DH = month (1 to 12) 
> DL = day of month(1 to 31) 
> ==> AL = day number in week (0 to 6 = Sunday to Saturday) 
> Notes:  The format of the registers returned by this call is the same as that required by Function 2Bh. Although shown above as decimal values for clarity, all values are in hex.
> ```